# WordPress permalinks that end with a hyphen result in a 404

Tags: permalinks

I have a series of URLs where the permalink ends with a hyphen. They come from a previous CMS where this apparently wasn't an issue, but in WordPress they result in a 404.

I'm noticing that when I edit the permalink in the CMS and remove the hyphen, the URL starts working with and without the hyphen at the end, which is fine.

But since there are 600+ of these URLs, what is the best way to do a bulk fix for this case?

Comment: Refer to this url for updating slugs in your database. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409652/mysql-remove-very-last-character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could code a database patch in PHP/with the WordPress APIs, but since it sounds like you won't be repeating this process frequently, I think that's probably overkill. The most straightforward approach to bulk changes like this is a quick SQL update directly on the database.

---

### Bulk Update via SQL Query

One large exception to performing a bulk update with a direct SQL query is the case where the fields you intend to modify contain serialized data, in which case using PHP/the WordPress APIs or a [specialized tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) might prove more convenient.

Luckily, post slugs are stored as plain strings in the `post_name` field, so a query to remove trailing hyphens is fairly intuitive:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_name = TRIM(TRAILING "-" FROM post_name) WHERE post_name LIKE "%-"
```

Since direct SQL queries circumvent all manner of checks and balances, it is prudent to back up your database before executing any database-altering query.

---

### Link Redirection via Server Configuration

Since it sounds like this content has been around for while and you might have users attempting to access it using old, hyphen-terminated URLs, you may want to add a rewrite rule to your `.htaccess` file (or equivalent) in order to redirect old URLs to their new hyphen-less counterparts:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)-$ $1 [QSA,R=301,L]  # Redirect requests to hyphen-terminated URLs
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This may need to be modified to fit your installation's configuration. Note that it will interfere with any other functionality that depends on non-filesystem, hyphen-terminated URLs, if it exists.

Comment: But why the WP UI doesn't allow the trailing dash `-`? Is there any reason for that?